# Any trick to retaining/caching facts between playbooks

Tags: ansible

Are there any tricks to using facts acrosss playbooks.

If I have something like this in playbooks/foo.yml

```
- name: "setting facts"
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - { role: roles/register-facts, delegate_to: localhost, run_once: true }
    - { role: roles/some-role }

- name: "some task"
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - { role: roles/some-role-consuming-the-facts }
```

Also in a separte playbook, playbooks/foo2.yml

```
- name: "some ot her task"
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - { role: roles/some-other-role-consuming-the-facts }
```

Any way to take this approach. This is actually a very simplified example, this project is a rather large automation project and there are a few roles that set variables global to the entire collection, and are called frequently... it does things like create certs, talk to other API's, and etc... A whole bunch of stuff we don't want to do redundantly.

Thx for any help.

Comment: In Ansible, there is no such thing as persistent shared variables in the term of parallel computing. Instead, you might want to store, change, and read shared variables in any external storage, or database you like. The synchronization is up to you.

Comment: It's possible to cache gathered facts and inventory source data. See [Cache Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins).

Comment: Yea I tried using the dummy host thing but it was way too clunky and defeated the purpose of having concise code in the playbooks. That approach seems good for a small number of variables but this has over 150 variables being set. Thx for pointing that out though, it will prove useful in other playbooks.